# tag search using WP_Query

Tags: php, tags, mysql

I need to find only posts with a tag `forest gump`. I've tried: `new WP_Query('tag=forest+gump');`, `new WP_Query('tag=forest gump');`. However they both return ALL the posts and not only the posts with `forest gump` tag. Single tags (without spaces) work fine, though. Alternatives (like plain SQL) will work as well.

The entry tag line is `forest gump, forrest gump, questend`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new WP_Query(array('tag_slug__in' => array('forrest-gump', 'forest-gump', 'questend')));
```

`new WP_Query('tag=forrest+gump,forest+gump,questend');` should work too...

Comment: The `+` doesn't work, but the dashes work just fine. Thank you. Nevertheless, I didn't find this anywhere in the WP docs.

Comment: @Guy [WP_Query > Tag Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters)

Comment: @Rast, yes, I saw that page. Mind pointing out the paragraph that provides this information?

Comment: This displays every article of those tags when I query it..